# USB Full Speed polling interval

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver, microcontroller

I have 1 Full Speed (12 Mbps) `CDC-ACM` type `USB` device connected directly to a High Speed `(EHCI - 480 Mbps)` controller on a `SoC`.

When there is no user-space application opening the `CDC-ACM` device in linux, I see a pulse which is repeated every 1 ms (SOF). Once an application (example cat) opens the `CDC-ACM` device, I see a lot of IN tokens (~102) between 2 `SOF's` from the host and the device NAKs the IN token. We are suspecting the device is busy `NAKing` that it hampers its operation.

Q1: Is there a way to reduce the number of  IN tokens within the 1 ms interval?

Thanks
0_l_0

Comment: I have made some full-speed USB devices, and on all them, the IN/NAK transactions are handled in hardware without the need for intervention by the CPU, so they shouldn't be slowing down the system.  Secondly, if you really want help slowing down the IN tokens, shouldn't you give the model number of your SoC and a link to its datasheet?

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for your reply. I have no prior background in USB and  I have arrived at the same conclusion. The IN/NAK transactions are handled in hardware. The SoC I am currently using is a AR9344, you can get the datasheet from the following link http://cykey.ca/~cykey/airport/AR9344.pdf

Comment: This is not the place for that Gabor, but maybe if you post a detailed question with your device descriptors, USB packet traces, and all the other relevant details, someone could help you.